# Show a description for the tag even when the users enter a partial string for the tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

When I first click on the field to enter the tag, I see a list of some tags with their description.

[image: screenshot]

When I enter some characters because I want to select a tag I know, I only see a list of possible candidates, but no description.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

As you see in the second screenshot, the tags are shown without a description, but both the tags have an excerpt. The second screenshot is the one I took when editing the tags once the question has been posted.

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) has an excerpt that is the following one, but it is not visible as description when the autocomplete kicks in.

> A special moderator-only tag to mark important meta discussions. A question with this tag can be seen on the main site in a special sidebar in the questions list and when viewing individual questions.

It would help if the description would be shown even if this case; users who are selecting the wrong tag would have a chance more to notice they are not using the tag they should use.

<sub>The revision number for current revision is 2011.8.13.3.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice catch; this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is actually a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report.

The description was supposed to be shown there. The special tags have a default description that is used until someone changes the text, but default excerpts weren't handled correctly in the tag suggestions. Hence they came up empty.

Even though it looks identical, the first "you must use one of these tags" suggestion list actually uses different code, and that code handled the default excerpts correctly; thus the difference between the two situations.

After the next build of the sites, the excerpts will appear correctly.